# Yosemite com.apple.xpc.launchd error every 10 seconds

Tags: macos, error, launchd, logs

Every **10 seconds** i get this error in my console:

`20/10/14 19:35:56,840 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.viber.osx[9850]) Could not find and/or execute program specified by service: 45: Operation not supported: com.viber.osx
20/10/14 19:35:56,840 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.viber.osx) Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.`

Brand new MacBook Pro 2014, Yosemite OS X. Viber was installed two days ago. The error occurs even when Viber is running.

Even upon deleting Viber from *Applications*, an error still occurs:

`20/10/14 19:38:37,078 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.viber.osx[9870]) Could not find and/or execute program specified by service: 149: Could not find a bundle of the given identifier through LaunchServices: com.viber.osx`

Can anyone tell me what this is and why it happens? Any way to remedy it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Too bad i was posting before doing my own checking.

The solution was simple and shall be presented here for others who have the same issue: Simply launch Viber and go to **Preferences**, there, tell Viber not to launch on system startup. It will remove its LaunchDaemon entry and the error will disappear.

Needless to say, Viber should address this issue in their first App release targeted for Yosemite OS X.

Comment: Same problem here, and your suggested fix worked perfectly. As of now (Dec 2014), Viber has not fixed the app to avoid this. I'm running version compatible with Yosemite. Thank you!